Selection of spherical harmonics for the orbital calculation of electrons
As shown in this answer, the calculation of the electron probability in atoms is based on Spherical Harmonics and the resulting orbit probabilities usually have symmetry axes on the Cartesian coordinates.

This is completely natural because we think in our three-dimensional space.
On the other hand, the orbitals are not observable and the chemical compounds rather point to tetrahedral structures ($sp^3$-hybridization, which can be accommodated in 4 corners of a cube) as well as to two noble gases in the Periodic table of elements with 2-8 and 2-8-8 electrons. These could be accommodated in the corners of a cube according to Gilbert N. Lewis‘ Valence theory. Now Lewis' assumption has been rejected, but - and here comes the question - would the use of a spherical harmonics of the form $$l=3, m=2, l-m=1$$ give worse results than the previously used basis?

(Remark: The sphere is unfolded and you can also see partially its rear part. There are 8 areas that correspond to the corners of a cube in their arrangement)

@Ghoster Edited. Thank you.
